# Shared variable in Python Process subclass

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pywin32

I was wondering if it would be possible to create some sort of static set in a Python Process subclass to keep track the types processes that are currently running asynchronously.

```
class showError(Process):
    # Define some form of shared set that is shared by all Processes
    displayed_errors = set()

    def __init__(self, file_name, error_type):
        super(showError, self).__init__()
        self.error_type = error_type

    def run(self):
        if error_type not in set:
            displayed_errors.add(error_type)
            message = 'Please try again. ' + str(self.error_type)
            winsound.MessageBeep(-1)
            result = win32api.MessageBox(0, message, 'Error', 0x00001000)

            if result == 0:
                displayed_errors.discard(error_type)
```

That way, when I create/start multiple showError processes with the same error_type, subsequent error windows will not be created. So how can we define this shared set?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`multiprocessing.Manager.dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.dict) (there's no `set` object available, but you can use a `dict` in the same way) and share that between all your subprocesses.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = mp.Manager()
    displayed_errors = m.dict()
    subp = showError("some filename", "some error type", displayed_errors)
```

Then change `showError.__init__` to accept the shared dict:

```
def __init__(self, file_name, error_type, displayed_errors):
    super(showError, self).__init__()
    self.error_type = error_type
    self.displayed_errors = displayed_errors
```

Then this:

```
displayed_errors.add(error_type)
```

Becomes:

```
self.displayed_errors[error_type] = 1
```

And this:

```
displayed_errors.discard(error_type)
```

Becomes:

```
try:
    del self.displayed_errors[error_type]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Does this mean that I will have to create a new instance of displayed_errors every time I create a showError process?

Comment: @user1927638 You just create `displayed_errors` once in your main process, and then pass it to each `showError` process. Each `showError` process will have its own instance of a __proxy__ to the actual `displayed_errors`. So there's one copy of the actual dict, and each process has its own proxy to it.

Comment: One thing to consider is that I am currently creating a showError process form a separate module. Ideally, I would really like to keep it in the module that showError is in or within the Process subclass itself.

Comment: @user1927638 On Linux, you can just define the `Manager` and `m.dict` inside the `Test` class. But this doesn't work on Windows (which it looks like you're using). This is because creating a `Manager` spawns a new process, which has to be protected by `if __name__ == "__main__"` on Windows.